# Error when using npm install angular2 --save

Tags: angular, npm

I'm following along in a Tuts+ tutorial on Angular. In this video: https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/whats-new-in-angular-2/lessons/angular-2-and-es5 the author says to type the following command:

`npm install angular2 --save`

I tried that, as well as using `sudo` in front of it as well, but get the following errors:

```
npm WARN package.json angular2tuts@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json angular2tuts@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json angular2tuts@1.0.0 No README data
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "angular2" "--save"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: angular2@'*'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["2.0.0-alpha.8.dev","2.0.0-alpha.8.prod","2.0.0-alpha.11","2.0.0-alpha.12","2.0.0-alpha.13","2.0.0-alpha.14","2.0.0-alpha.15","2.0.0-alpha.16","2.0.0-alpha.17","2.0.0-alpha.18","2.0.0-alpha.19","2.0.0-alpha.20","2.0.0-alpha.21","2.0.0-alpha.22","2.0.0-alpha.23","2.0.0-alpha.24","2.0.0-alpha.25","2.0.0-alpha.26","2.0.0-alpha.27","2.0.0-alpha.28","2.0.0-alpha.29","2.0.0-alpha.30","2.0.0-alpha.31","2.0.0-alpha.32","2.0.0-alpha.33","2.0.0-alpha.34","2.0.0-alpha.35","2.0.0-alpha.36","2.0.0-alpha.37","2.0.0-alpha.38","2.0.0-alpha.39","2.0.0-alpha.40","2.0.0-alpha.41","2.0.0-alpha.42","2.0.0-alpha.44","2.0.0-alpha.45","2.0.0-alpha.46","2.0.0-alpha.47","2.0.0-alpha.48","2.0.0-alpha.49","2.0.0-alpha.50","2.0.0-alpha.51","2.0.0-alpha.52","2.0.0-alpha.53","2.0.0-alpha.54","2.0.0-alpha.55","2.0.0-beta.0","2.0.0-beta.1"]
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

[image]

thoughts?

The author is able to do it fine without errors:

[image]

Comment: You can do `npm install angular2@SPECIFIC_VERSION` where *SPECIFIC_VERSION* is one of the shown in the error, or use `npm install angular2@latest --save`

Comment: Ah thanks! That was it :D `@latest` want to post your answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install angular2 using npm you can either specify the version or use `@latest`

- Specifying a version

```
npm install angular2@2.0.0-beta.1 --save
```

- Using `latest` (this will obviously install the latest version available in npm)

```
npm install angular2@latest --save
```

Note as well that there are plans to support `angular@next` that would add the posibility to install *nightly* builds, but it's not yet supported (so far snapshots are released from time to time, but the command is not yet available). Check [issue #4671](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4671) for more info.